# Pandas - Column value conversions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

**My data**: I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({
   'salary_frequency': ['Annual', 'Annual', 'Hourly', 'Hourly', 'Annual', 'Monthly'], 
   'salary_range_low': [51907.68, 51907.85, 35, 35, 50598, 4000]})
```

The values in `salary_range_low` are based on `salary_frequency` (`['Daily', 'Hourly' or 'Annual']`).

**My question**: How can I convert all `salary_range_low` to annual values for better comparison?

Comment: First, what is your desired output? Second, did you try anything the error message told you and understand it, say the `.loc` thing that might be the key to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map`:

```
# modify this to fit your need
maps = pd.Series([1, 365, 365*24], index=['Annually', 'Daily', 'Hourly'])

df['salary_range_low'] *= df['salary_frequency'].map(maps)
```

Comment: I would consider working days in a year, which typically are 252-253 and not 365.

Comment: @FBruzzesi Agreed, I'm just too lazy and leave it for OP :-).

Answer (score 2):

```
factor_mapper = {'Hourly': 8 * 253, 'Daily': 253, 'Annual': 1}
df['salary_range_low'] = df['salary_range_low'] * df['salary_frequency'].map(factor_mapper)
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need some notion of how the one one (e.g. "Hourly") translates to year. Once you have that translation, like below:

```
map_dict = {'Annual': 1, 'Hourly': 1880, 'Monthly': 12}
```

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and multiply:

```
df['per_year'] = df['salary_frequency'].map(map_dict) * df['salary_range_low']
df
```

**note:** The 1880 hours is based on 47 working 40-hour working weeks per year